# Chartist.js add graph in a modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, chartist.js

I have a small problem using the library Chartist.js ([Link](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/)). I'm able to reproduce a graph on the html pages but, when I try tu put in a bootstrap modal, the graph just squeeze to 1 pixel. Example of this can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/qw2Lnqng/4/. I udnerstood that the problem is due to the fact that the graph doesn't know the available space. The same happens with the tab ([Link](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/119)). The solution with the tab is here: http://jsbin.com/bawofakogu/1/edit?html,js,output. The solution was to add this piece of code:

```
$('[data-tab]').on('toggled', function (event, tab) {
tab.find('.ct-chart').each(function(i, e) {
  e.__chartist__.update();
});
});
```

I have tried to do the same with the modal but without success. Can you please show me hot wo solve this problem?

Thanks All!

Comment: Just to give you a feedback : the JsFiddle code works for me (I see the chart with a correct and readable size in the modal). It worked when I opened the modal then opened the Web tool kit from my browser (F12). So when the viewport reoslution is refreshed.

Answer (score 9):

Ok I found a solution. You can update the chart after the modal begin show; by using this jQuery piece of code :

First of all, store your chart in a variable :

```
 var yourchart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
           labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
           series: [
                  [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
                  [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
                  [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
           ]
           }, {
              fullWidth: true,
              chartPadding: {
                  right: 40
              }
});
```

Then with this code, you'll be able to update your chart to the new size of it's container :

```
$('#popOverlay').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
     yourchart.update();
});
```

Comment: For anyone using Foundation, use this event binding `$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', function (e) yourChart.update();}); `